# Displaying highest and lowest number values in C

Tags: c

I am new to programming and I am trying to finish a programming exercise in which the teacher (user) will input grades and will be continuously prompted to do so until they enter "-1." When it is entered, the prompt will end and it should output the average of all user-inputted grades, along with the highest and lowest grade inputted.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int counter;
   float average;
    int grade, total, max, min;

    total=0;
   counter=0;
   max=100;
   min=0;

   printf("Please enter grades, enter -1 to stop\n");
   scanf ("%d", &grade);
   max=min=grade;

   while ( grade !=-1 ) {
       total = total+ grade;
       counter= counter +1;
       if (grade > max)
       max = grade;
       if (grade < min)
       min = grade;
       printf("Please enter grades, enter -1 to stop\n");
   scanf ("%d", &grade);
   max=min=grade;
   }

if ( counter !=0 ) {
    average = (float) total / counter;
    printf("Your average is %.2f\n",average);
    printf("Your highest grade is %d\n", max);
    printf("Your lowest grade is %d\n", min);
}
  else {
      printf("No grades were entered\n");
  }

}
```

Here is an example input that results from the code:

```
Please enter grade, enter -1 to stop                                                                            
95                                                                                                              
Please enter grade, enter -1 to stop                                                                            
87                                                                                                              
Please enter grade, enter -1 to stop                                                                            
-1                                                                                                              
Your average is 91.00                                                                                           
Your highest grade is -1                                                                                        
Your lowest grade is -1
```

I cannot figure out why it wont display the proper values, with 95 being the highest and 87 being the lowest in this case. I would appreciate any help since it is the only part of the program I need to solve.

Thank you.

Comment: remove max=min=grade in the while loop

Comment: Really no reason to set max to 100, prior to setting it to the input. Once you get this working, you could get feedback on it on Code Review.

Comment: Removing the max=min-grade in the while loop actually got it to work! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the while loop you are mentioning *min=max=grade* the second time in the program.
That is taking the value of -1 from grade which is used to stop the program.
Please comment that line and try it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int counter;
   float average;
    int grade, total, max, min;

    total=0;
   counter=0;
   max=100;
   min=0;

   printf("Please enter grades, enter -1 to stop\n");
   scanf ("%d", &grade);
   max=min=grade;

   while ( grade !=-1 ) 
  {
       total = total+ grade;
       counter= counter +1;
       if (grade > max)
        {
         max = grade;
        }
       if (grade < min)
        {
         min = grade;
        }
       printf("Please enter grades, enter -1 to stop\n");
   scanf ("%d", &grade);

   }

if ( counter !=0 ) 
{
    average = (float) total / counter;
    printf("Your average is %.2f\n",average);
    printf("Your highest grade is %d\n", max);
    printf("Your lowest grade is %d\n", min);
}

  else 
{
      printf("No grades were entered\n");
  }
```